# Multithreading has no effect in performance

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, packet-sniffers

I am working on my packet sniffer. there is a workerConnection() function that performs main processes on packets as follow .
It reads a packet from _Connection_buffer that is defined as `std::string* _Connection_buffer= new std::string[_Max_Element_Connection_buffer]`, then splits the packets by its white spaces and performs some actions on them.
everythings works well except performance of parallel processing of workerConnection().

As it can be seen in the workerConnection(), in the first loop, each thread takes a unique number as its own 'MyID'. then uses its MyID as an offset for reading packets from  _Connection_buffer.

I am sure by parallel processing of workerConnection() each thread does not process all packets and only process (_Max_Element_Connection_buffer/_ConnectionThreadCount) packets.

```
void
workerConnection() {
    short MyID = 0;
    _Connection_tn->_mtx.lock();

    for (int n = 0; n < _ConnectionThreadCount; n++) {
        if (_Connection_tn->getMyNumber[n] != 100) {
            MyID = _Connection_tn->getMyNumber[n];
            _Connection_tn->getMyNumber[n] = 100;
            break;
        }
    }
    _Connection_tn->_mtx.unlock();
    LOG_INFO("Session Worker :%d started", MyID);
    long int index = 0;
    s_EntryItem* entryItem = NULL; 
    uint32_t srcIP_num;
    uint64_t p_counter=0;

    std::string connectionPayload1 = "";         connectionPayload1.reserve(40);
    std::string connectionPayload2 = "";         connectionPayload2.reserve(40);
    std::string connectionPayload = "";         connectionPayload.reserve(150);

    std::string part;         part.reserve(30);
    std::string srcIP_str;    srcIP_str.reserve(15);
    std::string t;            t.reserve(50);
    std::string line;         line.reserve(_snapLengthConnection + 1);
    std::string Protocol;     Protocol.reserve(3);
    std::string srcIP_port;   Protocol.reserve(7);

    std::vector<std::string> _CStorage(_storage_Count_Connection);
    struct timeval start, end;
    long mtime, secs, usecs;        
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    for (index = MyID; index < _Max_Element_Connection_buffer; index+=_ConnectionThreadCount) {                        
        if (unlikely(p_counter++ >= (_Connection_flag->_Number - MyID)) ) { 
            LOG_INFO("sleeped");
            boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(20));
            continue;
        }
        line = _Connection_buffer[index];
        if(line.size()<_storage_Count_Connection)
            continue;
        part = line.substr(_column_ConnectionConditionLocation, ConnectionCondition.length() + 5);
        if (part.find("My Packet") == std::string::npos) {      //assume always false.
            LOG_INFO("Part: %s, Condition: %s", part.c_str(), ConnectionCondition.c_str());
            continue;
        }                                    
        boost::split(_CStorage,line,boost::is_any_of(" "));
        t = _CStorage[_column_ConnectionUserIP];   
        auto endSource = t.find("/", 0);
        srcIP_str = t.substr(0, endSource);
        try {
            srcIP_num = boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string(srcIP_str).to_ulong();
        } catch (...) {
            continue;
        }
        entryItem = searchIPTable(srcIP_num);
        if (entryItem == NULL) {
            continue;
        }
        int ok = processConnection(srcIP_num, connectionPayload1, connectionPayload2, &_CStorage);
        if (!ok) {
            continue;
        }
        auto startSource = t.find("/", 8) + 1;
        endSource = t.find("-", startSource);            
        connectionPayload2+=t.substr(startSource, endSource - startSource);

        connectionPayload2+=_CStorage[_column_ConnectionProtocol];

        entryItem->_mtx.lock();
        if (entryItem->InUse != false) {
            connectionPayload = entryItem->payload1;
            connectionPayload += connectionPayload1;
            connectionPayload += entryItem->payload2;
            connectionPayload += connectionPayload2;
        }
        entryItem->_mtx.unlock();
    }
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
    secs  = end.tv_sec  - start.tv_sec;
    usecs = end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec;
    mtime = ((secs) * 1000 + usecs/1000.0) + 0.5;
    LOG_INFO("Worker %d :Elapsed time for %lu times running Connection Worker is %ld millisecs\n",MyID,index, mtime);  

    LOG_INFO("Connection Worker %d :stopped",MyID);
}
```

so now, there is a problem that drives me crazy . processing all the packets using one or 2 or n threads takes equal time.
as said earlier,  on multithreading, i am sure each threads process only _Max_Element_Connection_buffer/_ConnectionThreadCount packets.

I ran my program on a virtual ubuntu 14.04 which has 20G RAM and 4 CPUs. the host OS windows 8 and has 8 CPUs. 
the specification of one of my vitual ubuntu processor is shown below:

> processor : 3
>
> vendor_id : GenuineIntel
>
> cpu family    : 6
>
> model     : 60
>
> model name    : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4460  CPU @ 3.20GHz
>
> stepping  : 3
>
> cpu MHz       : 3192.718
>
> cache size    : 6144 KB
>
> physical id   : 0
>
> siblings  : 4
>
> core id       : 3
>
> cpu cores : 4

the results of processing my program with 1, 2, 4 and 8  threads are as follow:

Number of _Connection_buffer elements= 10,000

using one thread:

```
Worker 0 :Elapsed time for 10000 times running Connection Worker is 149 millisecs
```

using 2 threads:

```
Worker 0 :Elapsed time for 10000 times running Connection Worker is 122 millisecs
Worker 1 :Elapsed time for 10001 times running Connection Worker is 127 millisecs

using 4 threads:
Worker 0 :Elapsed time for 10000 times running Connection Worker is 127 millisecs
Worker 1 :Elapsed time for 10002 times running Connection Worker is 129 millisecs
Worker 2 :Elapsed time for 10001 times running Connection Worker is 138 millisecs
Worker 3 :Elapsed time for 10003 times running Connection Worker is 140 millisecs
```

using 8 threads.

```
Worker 0 :Elapsed time for 10007 times running Connection Worker is 135 millisecs
Worker 1 :Elapsed time for 10000 times running Connection Worker is 154 millisecs
Worker 2 :Elapsed time for 10002 times running Connection Worker is 153 millisecs
Worker 3 :Elapsed time for 10003 times running Connection Worker is 158 millisecs
Worker 4 :Elapsed time for 10006 times running Connection Worker is 169 millisecs
Worker 5 :Elapsed time for 10004 times running Connection Worker is 170 millisecs
Worker 6 :Elapsed time for 10005 times running Connection Worker is 176 millisecs
Worker 7 :Elapsed time for 10001 times running Connection Worker is 178 millisecs
```

Comment: On a quick look at both your code and the output, it appears very thread does about the same amount of work.   Which means 4 threads would do 4 times as much work as a single thread .... and each thread would take the same amount of time.   Which means your problem is the logic of measurement.